# PRTSC and paste in Excel using python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, openpyxl, pywinauto

I have written a small script using python 3.7 which automates the following stuff:

->opens a specific application on desktop

->loads a excel workbook and reads a column which contains timings

->picks the time from excel(each row) and go to the opened application and navigates to the time

->PRTSC the desktop and saves as a temp.png

->goes the excel and create a new worksheet in the same workbook and pastes the temp.png

```
import pywinauto
import openpyxl
from PIL import ImageGrab
#starts a application
#loads a workbook
for i in range(2,ws.max_row+1):
        #grabs the timing from the row of a column
        #navigates in the application using the timing
        wb.create_sheet(s)
        dlg=app.top_window() #my application is on top
        dlg.type_keys('{PRTSC}')
        time.sleep(1)
        ws1=wb[s]
        im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
        im.save('temp.png','PNG')
        img = drawing.image.Image('temp.png')
        time.sleep(1)
        j+=1
        ws1.add_image(img,'A'+str(40*j+1)) #pastes the image after every 40 cells 
        time.sleep(1)
wb.save(newsample.xlsx)
```

so, the script executes perfectly and i get the new excel(newsample.xlsx) with the images, but the problem here is that all the images are just the latest image(temp.png) which is captured at the last step.

I assume there is a  issue with drawing.image.Image/add_image line

should i save the wb each step of the loop???

or are there any other packages/modules for capturing images and pasting in excel???

Comment: You might try using a timestamp for the image name. openpyxl doesn't do any management for images files.

Comment: Where variable `j` is defined first time? I see just `j += 1` in the code.

Comment: yes @CharlieClark, i tried almost the same way , i.e. im.save('temp'+str(i)+'.png','PNG') , so that each image is saved with diff name(my pc is getting filled with 100's of temp images). i was just wondering why the above issue happens or any other work around possible...